# Mapping a set with the function $z^2$ in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following set:

$G=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \Im{(z)}>0, \Re{(z)}<0 \}$

$f(z) = z^2$

I need to draw $ f(G) $ but I don't get a good answer using $ z=x+iy $ and trying to understand the complex plane with information on the cartesian plane.

How do I go about it?
I understand that G is the upper left quarter of the complex plane and I know the answer is the lower half plane but I need to see the steps.

after that I need to write $ f(G) $. Would like to see that too.

Follow up question:

This time the function is $f(z) = log(z)$ and the set is:

$G=\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|>0, -\pi < arg(z) < \pi \}$

I don't have an intuition of what the log function does to the given set so I'd appreciate a calculation.

Comment: Are you familiar with the geometric interpretation of complex multiplication, where multiplying two complex numbers means adding their polar angles and multiplying their absolute values? So squaring means doubling the polar angle and squaring the absolute value. Now consider what happens to any straight line through the origin if you square every point on the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may rewrite

$$G=\{z\in\Bbb{C},|z|\gt 0,\,{\pi\over 2}\lt\arg{z}\lt\pi\}$$

Squaring means squaring the module and doubling the argument

So

$$f(G)=\{z\in\Bbb{C},|z|\gt 0,\,\pi\lt\arg{z}\lt 2\pi\}$$

And so $f(G)$ is the lower half plane

For the follow up consider the following

$$\log{r\cdot e^{i\theta}}=\log{r}+i \theta$$

This means that the image by logarithm of $H$ the right half plane is the horizontal strip $\{z\in\Bbb{C},-\pi\lt\operatorname{Im}{z}\lt\pi\}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I still don't have a firm grip of these type of problems, would you answer the edit as well?